# Select all the (varied number of ) rows with the latest date

Tags: mysql

A MySQL database with data as follows:

```
project_id | updated             | next_steps 
1          | 2014-08-01 03:19:20 | new_com         
2          | 2014-08-12 03:20:34 | NULL            
3          | 2014-08-12 07:01:12 | NULL            
4          | 2014-08-05 09:25:45 | comment
```

I want to select all the rows with the latest **date** in the column of 'update'.  The difference in hours/minutes should be ignored.  I expected to get the row 2 and row 3 from this example as follows:

```
2          | 2014-08-12 03:20:34 | NULL            
3          | 2014-08-12 07:01:12 | NULL
```

Of course, for the real table, the number of rows meet my criteria is changed daily and the numbers could be 100, 200, 324, etc. (it is not a fixed number).  I have tried the following code and always get errors.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE updated LIKE %DATE(MAX(updated))%;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE updated LIKE %CAST(DATE(MAX(updated)) AS CHAR)%;
```

Error message is

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%CAST(DATE(MAX(updated)) AS CHAR)% LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"

Comment: You want to use the `ORDER BY` query

Comment: ORDER BY will list latest rows first, but will list all the rows, right?  I only want to list the rows with the last date.

Comment: Do you mean ignore the time part of the date? Otherwise, you could just use `LIMIT 1` to only select the latest one

Comment: I want to have ALL the rows with the last date, not just the single row with the last date + last time.  The number of rows I want changes day-to-day, which could 100, or 200 rows.

Comment: Alright. Looking into it.

Comment: Figured it out, editing my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT MAX(DATE(updated)) FROM table`(this returns the `2014-08-12`) use this as sub query. This gives back the max date. For example: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(updated) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(updated)) FROM table)` The sub query gives back the max date you want, after that you can query the right rows. This returns all the lines that were updated at the max date.

Comment: Hi, C1sc0, you pointed at the right direction.  Your code needs minor modification as: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(updated) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(updated)) FROM table)`, which works perfectly!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Darn!, I was just seconds off! +1 for the correction

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `WHERE` query and use `DATE(x)` to calculate the maximum date without time and then select all values with that date without time.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`updated`) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(`updated`)) FROM `table`)
```

And if you still want them ordered

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE DATE(`updated`) = (SELECT MAX(DATE(`updated`)) FROM `table`) ORDER BY `updated` DESC
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: The true # of rows meets my criteria is variable daily and could be 100, or 134, or 345, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you want two data,

```
   SELECT * FROM `table`  order by  'updated'     desc limt 2
```

Comment: This doesn't serve my goal.  I wants only, but all of the rows with the last date. All other rows with older dates in 'updated' should not show up.

Comment: The true # of rows meets my criteria is variable daily and could be 100, or 134, or 345, etc.

Comment: You need a sub query to get the latest date, then query using the result          `` select  * from  'table' where  CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, updated)))  =(SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, updated)) as latest  FROM ``table``  )``